# Image not Showing in crystal report viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report version 13.0.16.1954, In the data which is displayed in Crystal Report Viewer (Main report preview in visual studio 2013) having the images. When i am trying run the reports in the Crystal Report viewer in browser, Images are not showing up.Image showing as a label.Report screen shot was attached in below.

Can any one help me to fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVb9y.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

adding the following handllers to the web.config solved my issue

the important point make sure to remove the precondition tag

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>


<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the handler to your config file? Hopefully, this line of code will help you on your development.

Comment: I have added this line to httpHandler  <br/><add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>

Comment: haven't tried adding it to httpHandler. can you like transfer it to your config and see if it works?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: hi @user7702234 . Can you locate your web.config file?